# Query with integers not working

Tags: database, postgresql

I've been searching here on stackoverflow and other sources but not found a solution to this

The query below works as expected expect for when either `custinfo.cust_cntct_id` or `custinfo.cust_corrcntct_id = ''` (blank not `NULL`) then I get no results. Both are integer fields and if both have an integer value then I get results.  I still want a value returned for either `cntct_email` or `corrcntct_email` even if `custinfo.cust_cntct_id` or `custinfo.cust_corrcntct_id = blank`

Can someone help me out in making this work? The database is PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT 
  cntct.cntct_email AS cntct_email, 
  corrcntct.cntct_email AS corrcntct_email
FROM 
  public.custinfo, 
  public.invchead, 
  public.cntct, 
  public.cntct corrcntct
WHERE 
  invchead.invchead_cust_id = custinfo.cust_id AND
  cntct.cntct_id = custinfo.cust_cntct_id AND
  corrcntct.cntct_id = custinfo.cust_corrcntct_id;
```

Comment: Please show `psql` `\d` output or `create table` statements for the tables, and your PostgreSQL version from `select version();`

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL won't actually let you test an integer field for a blank value (unless you're using a truly ancient version - 8.2 or older), so you must be using a query generator that's "helpfully" transforming `''` to `NULL` or a tool that's ignoring errors.

Observe this, on Pg 9.2:

```
regress=> CREATE TABLE test ( a integer );
CREATE TABLE
regress=> insert into test (a) values (1),(2),(3);
INSERT 0 3
regress=> SELECT a FROM test WHERE a = '';
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
LINE 1: SELECT a FROM test WHERE a = '';
```

If you are attempting to test for `= NULL`, [this is not correct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html). You must use `IS NOT NULL` or `IS DISTINCT FROM NULL` instead. Testing for `= NULL` always results in `NULL`, which is treated as false in a `WHERE` clause.

Example:

```
regress=> insert into test (a) values (null);
INSERT 0 1

regress=> SELECT a FROM test WHERE a = NULL;
 a 
---
(0 rows)

regress=> SELECT a FROM test WHERE a IS NULL;
 a 
---

(1 row)

regress=> SELECT NULL = NULL as wrong, NULL IS NULL AS right;
 wrong | right 
-------+-------
       | t
(1 row)
```

---

By the way, you should really be using ANSI JOIN syntax. It's more readable and it's much easier to forget to put a condition in and get a cartesian product by accident. I'd rewrite your query for identical functionality and performance but better readability as:

```
SELECT 
  cntct.cntct_email AS cntct_email, 
  corrcntct.cntct_email AS corrcntct_email
FROM 
  public.custinfo ci
  INNER JOIN public.invchead
    ON (invchead.invchead_cust_id = ci.cust_id)
  INNER JOIN public.cntct 
    ON (cntct.cntct_id = ci.cust_cntct_id)
  INNER JOIN public.cntct corrcntct 
    ON (corrcntct.cntct_id = ci.cust_corrcntct_id);
```

Use of table aliases usually keeps it cleaner; here I've aliased the longer name `custinfo` to `ci` for brevity.